# Parsing a string

Tags: c#

I want to parse a string to long the value is 1.0010412473392E+15.But it gives a exception input string was not in a correct format.how to do this.

Both these answers work how to select both of them as answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the **[`System.Globalization.NumberStyles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberstyles.aspx)** enumeration in the appropriate overload of Int64.Parse.  If you specify `System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any`, it should work:

```
long v = Int64.Parse(s, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any);
```

Note, however that the number you are parsing has limited precision, (there are only 13 decimal places but is specified as E+15).  Also, the 'Any' enumeration is probably more than you really need - in this case you only need `AllowDecimalPoint` and `AllowExponent`:

```
long v = Int64.Parse(s, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint | System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowExponent);
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you don't want to parse to `double`?

```
var myDouble = double.Parse(myString);
```

You can then try converting to `long`.

```
var myLong = Convert.ToInt64(myDouble);
```